# Invalid container in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I am new to Orchard CMS and i am developing a module.
I have a content part which is attached to another part. It's a blog post and few details like a post number (a running number for the current year). I can get to the create screen but after creation it says Invalid container. As a result the post is not created.

Any help / suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I don't think you can attach a content part to another content part - you can only attach content parts to content types, so you might want to clarify your statement here.

Furthermore, if you have any code written that relates to this functionality, you should share the relevant snippets here.

If you didn't write any code, then please provide repro steps.

Comment: Thanks , I removed the part . now it is good.